# Getting org.testng.TestNGException: Cannot find class in classpath: error in eclipse during running my program through testng.xml

Tags: java, maven, selenium, testng

This is my Test Class , the code is like below , I have checked solutions mentioned already but couldn't be able to fix the issue .I am using a maven project and running the script by running the testng.xml.
can any one please help me. I am also providing the content of my testng.xml and error message.
Appreciate for your help.

```
    package com.orangehrmlivetestcases;

    import org.testng.annotations.AfterMethod;
    import org.testng.annotations.BeforeMethod;
    import org.testng.annotations.Test;

    import com.orangehrmlive.pages.Home_DashboardPage;
    import com.orangehrmlive.pages.LoginpanelPage;
    import com.orangehrmlive.setup.Base_Setup;

    public class LoginpanelPageTest extends Base_Setup {

        LoginpanelPage login;
        Home_DashboardPage homepage;

        public LoginpanelPageTest() {

            super();
        }

        @BeforeMethod
        public void setup() {

            initialization();
            login = new LoginpanelPage();
        }

        @Test(priority = 1)
        public void validateErrormessageTest() {

            login.verify_message_Blank_Details();
        }

        @Test(priority = 2)
        public void validatesuccesfulloginTest() {

            homepage = login.verify_succesfull_login();
        }

        @AfterMethod
        public void teardown() {

            driver.quit();
        }

    }
```

testng.xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
    <suite name="Suite">
      <test thread-count="1" name="Test">
        <classes>

          <class name="com.orangehrmlivetestcases.LoginpanelPageTest"/>

        </classes>
      </test> <!-- Test -->
    </suite> <!-- Suite -->
```

Error message :

```
    [RemoteTestNG] detected TestNG version 6.14.2
    org.testng.TestNGException: 
    Cannot find class in classpath: com.orangehrmlivetestcases.LoginpanelPageTest
        at org.testng.xml.XmlClass.loadClass(XmlClass.java:77)
        at org.testng.xml.XmlClass.init(XmlClass.java:69)
        at org.testng.xml.XmlClass.<init>(XmlClass.java:55)
        at org.testng.xml.TestNGContentHandler.startElement(TestNGContentHandler.java:575)
        at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.startElement(AbstractSAXParser.java:509)
        at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractXMLDocumentParser.emptyElement(AbstractXMLDocumentParser.java:183)
        at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.dtd.XMLDTDValidator.emptyElement(XMLDTDValidator.java:767)
        at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:351)
        at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:2706)
        at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:602)
        at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:112)
        at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:532)
        at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:888)
        at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:824)
        at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:141)
        at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1213)
        at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:635)
        at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:324)
        at java.xml/javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser.parse(SAXParser.java:197)
        at org.testng.xml.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:38)
        at org.testng.xml.SuiteXmlParser.parse(SuiteXmlParser.java:16)
        at org.testng.xml.SuiteXmlParser.parse(SuiteXmlParser.java:9)
        at org.testng.xml.Parser.parse(Parser.java:152)
        at org.testng.xml.Parser.parse(Parser.java:233)
        at org.testng.TestNG.parseSuite(TestNG.java:295)
        at org.testng.TestNG.initializeSuitesAndJarFile(TestNG.java:348)
        at org.testng.TestNG.initializeEverything(TestNG.java:995)
        at org.testng.remote.support.RemoteTestNG6_12.initialize(RemoteTestNG6_12.java:22)
        at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:98)
        at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:251)
        at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:77)
```

Project screenshot:

Comment: Can you please add the project screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

I hope you have added a maven integrating with testing by adding a maven-surefire-plugin. Below is the plugin :

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>regression</id>

        <build>
            <pluginManagement><!-- lock down plugins versions to avoid using Maven defaults (may be moved to parent pom) -->
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>2.22.1</version>
                        <configuration>
                            <suiteXmlFiles>
                                <suiteXmlFile>testng.xml</suiteXmlFile>
                            </suiteXmlFiles>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </pluginManagement>
        </build>
    </profile>
```

Adding profile here is optional if you are having multiple TestNG XML files then profiles will help.